# Detect in which place I have most of all points

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to divide my form area up for 100 mini forms, and detect in which one I have most of all points. How can I write this simply?

This is my code:

```
bool isFound;
int[,] tab = new int[10, 10];
double widthX, widthY;
double X, Y;
widthX = (max.X - min.X) / 10.0;
widthY = (max.Y - min.Y) / 10.0;
X = min.X;
Y = min.Y;

foreach (Position pos in positionData)
{
    isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        X = min.X;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if ((pos.X >= X && pos.X < X + widthX) && (pos.Y >= Y && pos.Y < Y + widthY))
            {
                tab[i, j] += 1;
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
            X += widthX;
        }
        if (isFound) break;
        Y += widthY;
    }
}
```

Position is a struct with X and Y double variables. I don't know why but not all points are represent in my tab (for example when my positionData have 10 points, my tab only include 4 points).

Answer (score 0):

I think `if (isFound) break;` is your culprit. When you find a point in a little square, you abort searching in the squares left. I think this line should be removed (if I understood correctly what you are trying to do).